# Is it possible to format the nodes using html

Tags: cytoscape.js

is it possible to format nodes like this:

[image]

or should the label be formatted ? Any trail I should look for ?

Comment: This is so advanced. You might think about injecting HTML to nodes or just dynamically creating background images.

Comment: You can check https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-popper

Comment: thanks for the idea! I thought that popper was only for tooltips. So this would also work for labels ?

Comment: Actually it is just adding new DOM elements with absolute positions. You don't even need popper extension. I think it is a bit useless extension. You can just add your own DOM elements.

Comment: I finally used the nodeHtmlLabel extension for that purpose, it works rather well. Thanks though for your advices!